# Problems mapping in LUIS entities into form flow

Tags: botframework

I have problems when i try mapped the entities from LUIS. First, through a method, I complete the entities from LUIS, but, the bot ask me again about the entities that are already stuffed.

```
var state = new BookMeetingRoomForm(); 
var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities); 
if (entities.Count > 0) 
{ 
    FillEntityNewBookFromLuis(result, out state); 
    entities = null; 
} 
var formDialog = new FormDialog<BookMeetingRoomForm>(
    state, BookMeetingRoomForm.BuildForm, 
    FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities); 
context.Call(formDialog, Callback);
```

Nor does it work for me when mapping the entities directly, the error occurs:

> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is
>   not marked as serializable.

And the class is marked as [serializable]

Has anyone ever happened to you?

https://github.com/jesusom/Developments

thanks in advance:

Comment: Please put the relevant piece of codes where the problem is happening here; otherwise it will be hard to help as no one will go a read all your code in github.

Comment: Also, watch out! your code in github contains all your keys (db, bot, luis, etc)

Comment: var state = new BookMeetingRoomForm();
            var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);

            if (entities.Count > 0)
            {
                FillEntityNewBookFromLuis(result, out state);
                entities = null;
            }

            var formDialog = new FormDialog<BookMeetingRoomForm>(state, BookMeetingRoomForm.BuildForm
                      , FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities);

            context.Call(formDialog, Callback);

Comment: Yes, I was able to reproduce both issues. the one about JArray I think is an issue in botBuilder. the other one I'm still checking why is not working for you

Comment: Thanks again Ezequiel

Comment: For the serialization issue, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552030/json-serializer-error-with-botframework-an-luis/44552205#44552205 where I explained the root cause of it.

Comment: Thanks  Ezequiel. As for the second problem, I have a method that fills the values of LUIS, and then I pass it to the FormDialog, I should not ask again for the values filled, right?

Comment: I'm doing tests, and the enumerable type fields do not ask me again, however the date type fields, and numeric type if I ask again when in the entity are already stuffed

Comment: hi Ezequiel, Could you take a look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON serializer error with BotFramework an LUIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552030/json-serializer-error-with-botframework-an-luis)