# JSON serializer error with BotFramework an LUIS

Tags: c#, json, botframework, azure-language-understanding

StackOverflow Community!

I have a chatbot, and integrated LUIS.ai to make it smarter. One of the dialogues is about to Book an appointment with a Supervisor (Teacher)
Everything has been working fine, with literally the same code. A couple of hours ago I am experiencing some strange errors.

```
 Exception: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is not marked as serializable.
```

**How to reproduce the error?**

If the both Entity (Teacher and Date) is missing from the user's input it works FINE, the bot builds the Form, asking for missing inputs and presents the suggested meeting times.

If one of the Entity is missing it from input it will build a Form and asks for the missing Date or Teacher Entity and presents the suggested meeting times.

**BUT**

If the user's input contains both Entity: the Teacher and the Date too, then I am getting the error.

Here is my WebApiConfig class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Json settings
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };

            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

I am only experiencing this error when I am trying to get an Entity from the user utterance, which is a type of builtin.dateTimeV2.

This async method is called:

```
    //From the LUIS.AI language model the entities
    private const string EntityMeetingDate = "MeetingDate";
    private const string EntityTeacher = "Teacher";

    [LuisIntent("BookSupervision")]
public async Task BookAppointment(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
{
    var message = await activity;
    await context.PostAsync($"I am analysing your message: '{message.Text}'...");

    var meetingsQuery = new MeetingsQuery();

    EntityRecommendation teacherEntityRecommendation;
    EntityRecommendation dateEntityRecommendation;

    if (result.TryFindEntity(EntityTeacher, out teacherEntityRecommendation))
    {
        teacherEntityRecommendation.Type = "Name";
    }
    if (result.TryFindEntity(EntityMeetingDate, out dateEntityRecommendation))
    {
        dateEntityRecommendation.Type = "Date";
    }

    var meetingsFormDialog = new FormDialog<MeetingsQuery>(meetingsQuery, this.BuildMeetingsForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, result.Entities);
    context.Call(meetingsFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterMeetingsFormDialog);

}
```

Further methods for building a form:

```
 private IForm<MeetingsQuery> BuildMeetingsForm()
{
    OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<MeetingsQuery> processMeetingsSearch = async (context, state) =>
    {
        var message = "Searching for supervision slots";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.Date))
        {
            message += $" at {state.Date}...";
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.Name))
        {
            message += $" with professor {state.Name}...";
        }
        await context.PostAsync(message);
    };

    return new FormBuilder<MeetingsQuery>()
        .Field(nameof(MeetingsQuery.Date), (state) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.Date))
        .Field(nameof(MeetingsQuery.Name), (state) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.Name))
        .OnCompletion(processMeetingsSearch)
        .Build();
}

private async Task ResumeAfterMeetingsFormDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<MeetingsQuery> result)
{
try
{
    var searchQuery = await result;

    var meetings = await this.GetMeetingsAsync(searchQuery);

    await context.PostAsync($"I found {meetings.Count()} available slots:");

    var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();
    resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
    resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    foreach (var meeting in meetings)
    {
        HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = meeting.Teacher,
            Subtitle = meeting.Location,
            Text = meeting.DateTime,
            Images = new List<CardImage>()
            {
                new CardImage() {Url = meeting.Image}
            },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Book Appointment",
                    Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    Value = $"https://www.bing.com/search?q=easj+roskilde+" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(meeting.Location)
                }
            }
        };

        resultMessage.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
    }

    await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
}
catch (FormCanceledException ex)
{
    string reply;

    if (ex.InnerException == null)
    {
        reply = "You have canceled the operation.";
    }
    else
    {
        reply = $"Oops! Something went wrong :( Technical Details: {ex.InnerException.Message}";
    }

    await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
finally
{
    context.Wait(DeconstructionOfDialog);
}
}


private async Task<IEnumerable<Meeting>> GetMeetingsAsync(MeetingsQuery searchQuery)
{
    var meetings = new List<Meeting>();

    //some random result manually for demo purposes
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var random = new Random(i);
        Meeting meeting = new Meeting()
        {
            DateTime = $" Available time: {searchQuery.Date} At building {i}",
            Teacher = $" Professor {searchQuery.Name}",
            Location = $" Elisagårdsvej 3, Room {random.Next(1, 300)}",
            Image = $"https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=35&txt=Supervision+{i}&w=500&h=260"
        };

        meetings.Add(meeting);
    }

    return meetings;
}
```

The strangest thing that this code has worked, and my shoutout and respect goes for the community on GitHub, because I think this is an awesome platform with a tons of documentation and samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known issue (also reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544059/problems-mapping-in-luis-entities-into-form-flow) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2764)).

Long story short, since the builtin.datetimeV2.* entities are not yet supported in BotBuilder, the `Resolution` dictionary of the `EntityRecommendation` ends up with an entry with a value of type `JArray`. The problem arises when you pass those entities to a `FormDialog`. Since the entities are a private field in the dialog and of course, as any other dialog, is being serialized, an exception is being thrown because the `JArray` class from `Newtonsoft` is not marked as serializable.

The request for adding support for datetimeV2 entities is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2764).

The workaround I can think of right now is to extract the value of the DateTime entity manually and assign it your `Date` field of your `MeetingsQuery` instance you are passing to the `FormDialog` and also to remove the DateTime entity from the `result.Entities` collection that you are passing to the `FormDialog`.

**Update**

This is already fixed in the SDK as you can see in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2964).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ejadib for the help, what I did and it solved the error: deleted the MeetingDate composite entity with child **builtin.dateTimeV2** and added as a new custom (type: simple). Thanks again for your quick response! Keep up the good spirit!