# LUIS pre-built Entity 'datetimeV2' Throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to get date entity from LUIS

```
if (result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetimeV2.date", out dtEntityRecommendation))
```

this part of the my code throws exception
Type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` in Assembly `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed` is not marked as serializable.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of the BotBuilder SDK are u using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON serializer error with BotFramework an LUIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552030/json-serializer-error-with-botframework-an-luis)